# R Shiny App User Session Memory

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way I can determine the memory footprint of each user session for my Shiny app without having Shiny Server or shinyapps.io? The app is currently in my local environment.

Comment: `library(utils)` has `memory.size()` function that reports on memory allocation. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe that just determines R memory usage not associated with a particular session. I know that if you include session in your server function you can expose clientData, but that doesn't seem to include memory info.

Answer (score 0):

you can add  `renderprint({memory.size()})` or `renderprint({mem_used()})` from `pryr` package [[See]](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1551)